# convert list to dictionary with numbers

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

I want to convert this list into dictionary as follows

```
dictionary = {"1": "a", "2": "b", "3": "c", "4": "d", "5": "e"}
```

Here numbers should incremented based on the list length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{str(i): k for i, k in enumerate(list, 1) }
```

Change your `list` var name.

Note: passing a int to `enumerate(list, number)`, you can choose from what number the counting start.

Comment: thanks for the quick response and yes it worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{str(i + 1): v for i, v in enumerate(list)}
```

Please note that it is very unwise to call a list (or anything else) `list` (since you'd lose access to the `list` type).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. :)